# Can we have a personalized grub menu using simple-cdd

Tags: debian

I tried using simple-cdd to create a customised iso. I am looking for creating my own grub menu entry. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grub menu entries are build from files in */etc/grub.d/*.

Simple-CDD allows to add your own packages.

So you could build a package that provides a file in */etc/grub.d/* which in turn will generate the menu entry when update-grub is called.